# Counter dosent work on simple js jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formsets

After press on button the TOTAL_FORMS dosent update and i have the same number 1 i all lines like in quote lower.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-item').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var count = $('#items-form-container').children().length;
        var tmplMarkup = $('#item-template').html();
        var compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, count);
        $('div#items-form-container').append(compiledTmpl);

        // update form count
        $('#id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count + 1);
        // some animate to scroll to view our new form
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#add-item-button").position().top-200
            }, 800);
    });
});
```

I add 3 form but total count dosent update.

```
&form-TOTAL_FORMS=1
&form-INITIAL_FORMS=0
&form-MIN_NUM_FORMS=0
&form-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000
&form-0-good=5&form-0-count=14
&form-TOTAL_FORMS=1
&form-INITIAL_FORMS=0
&form-MIN_NUM_FORMS=0
&form-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000
&form-0-good=6&form-0-count=155
&form-TOTAL_FORMS=1
&form-INITIAL_FORMS=0
&form-MIN_NUM_FORMS=0
&form-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000
&form-0-good=12&form-0-count=55
```

What i need.

```
   'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
   'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
   'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
   'form-0-title': 'Test',
   'form-0-pub_date': '1904-06-16',
  'form-1-title': 'Test',
  'form-1-pub_date': '1912-06-23',
```

**UPD:**
How you say i add HTML code. Main trouble i use djnago for generate all data i try to create js fiddle

```
<script type="text/html" id="item-template">
<div id="item-__prefix__">
            {{ formset.as_p }}
</div>
</script>

<!--Example -->
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{csrf_token}}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<div id="items-form-container">
{% for item_form in formset %}
        <div id="item-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            {{ item_form.id }}
            {{ item_form.as_p}}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>



    <a href="#" id="add-item-button" class="btn btn-info add-item">Add Item</a>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-item').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var count = $('#items-form-container').children().length;
        var tmplMarkup = $('#item-template').html();
        var compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, count);
        $('div#items-form-container').append(compiledTmpl);
        // update form count
        $('#id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count + 1);
        // some animate to scroll to view our new form
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#add-item-button").position().top-200
            }, 800);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Cruiser why? it is counting the number of children...

Comment: So what does the template look like?

Comment: @Cruiser i dont work with js and jquery before i don`t know how to do this.

Comment: sorry, i didn't read the whole line of your count. it should be ok where it is. have you done a console.log(count) to see what the variable is holding?

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: This line is targeting an html element by ID  but I don't see this sam ID represented anywhere in what you have posted. So perhaps you have the wrond ID used here.   $('#id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count + 1);

Comment: @guest271314 I update main topic

Comment: Yep.  Given workable markup, the code seems fine.  Probably just a missing element of id `id_item_totals-TOTAL_FORMS`: https://jsfiddle.net/jwau70o9/ (attempt at creating a working version with markup before OP had posted the existing markup).

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thx but why all time couter + 2 ?

Comment: @user3170400 Stupid mistake on my part.  I had a `span` and a `br` as the template, but the code assumes that the template has one node.  I fixed my comment.

Comment: @user3170400 `html` at Question does not appear to contain element having `id`  `#id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS`  ?

Comment: @JosephMarikle it dosent help in my POST request i have the same TOTALFORMS=1

Comment: @user3170400 `TOTALFORMS` isn't even in your markup.  Where is it coming from?  As pointed out already, `id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS` isn't there either.